# trying to find an user by email an get "Called id for nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I'm working on a reset password action. But after click the button I get this error:

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Here is my password_reset_controller

```
 class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController

    layout "sessions"

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "#{user.id}Las instrucciones para reestrablecer la contrasena fueron enviadas."
  end

end
```

and Here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    def send_password_reset
        self.password_reset_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        self.password_reset_at = Time.zone.now
        save!
    end

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

this is the view:

```
<% provide(:title, "Reiniciar Password") %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        &nbsp
    </div>
    <div class="span4" id="login-box">  
        <div id="login-controls">
            <%= link_to(image_tag("logo.png"), root_path) %>
            <br>
            <br>

            <%= form_for(:password_resets, url: password_resets_path) do |f| %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Correo Electronico", :tabindex => 1, :style => "height:25px;" %>
                <%= f.button "<i class=\"icon-lock icon-white\"></i> Reiniciar Password".html_safe, :tabindex => 2,  class: "btn btn-warning", :style => "width:220px;margin-bottom:5px;" %>
            <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understan why I can't find the user; I try to do the same at rails console and I can find the user by email, but I can generate the password_reset_token.

Please I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the case of the email? it might be that the email has an uppercase in the database but not in your search.

Comment: Yes and I get the same error. Thanks to Manjunath Manohar I solve the problem like this user = User.find_by_email!(params[:password_resets][:email] ) but know I get this error Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank

Comment: Iam not sure, but for some reason your password is getting reset. Can you try by changing the attr_accessible to attr_accessor and try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use params[:password_resets][:email]

Please do `User.all` and see. check on which user record you invoked the password_reset_token method

This means that there is no user in your database with this email.

Use,

```
user = User.find_by_email!(params[:email])
```

method with a bang (!) will trigger an exception. `find_by_email` returns a nil object if the email was not found

Comment: But this user exist in my database. I attached the view; maybe I doing something wrong.

Comment: use params["email"]. Also install the debugger gem and inspect the params hash

Comment: did you try params["email"] ?

Comment: looking at your form it might be params[:password_resets][:email]

Comment: Yes, this worked, but know I have this error: Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank

Comment: Can you accept the answer.
Initialize the password_confirmation also with the same password
self.password_confirmation = self.password.

Comment: I still getting the same error Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank would you help me, please